# What team rebounded the best and worst?

Tags: american-football, nfl

My question is which team from a prior season did really good the next season.For example: team a gets a 3-13 record and is 30th team and next season gets a really good ranking(counting the playoffs so the superbowl winner is 1st, loser is 2nd and when multiple teams have same record like losing divisional,use regular season ranking for tiebreaker.)
So which team rebouded the best(the best possible is 32nd-1st) and which team rebounded the worst(worst possible is 1st-32nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

98 to 99 Colts: 3-13 ([tied for worst record in the NFL](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1998/)) to 13-3 ([tied for 2nd best record in the NFL](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1999/)).

You can take this information to determine where they finished (based on your scale).